# Find the gcd and write it a linear combination

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$24,-11$$

So we begin with $gcd(24,-11)$

$$24=-2*-11+2=gcd(-11,2)$$

$$-11=-6*2+1=gcd(2,1)=1$$

So $gcd(24,-11)=1$ now how do I find x,y such that $1=24x-11y$?

Comment: You are severely abusing the $=$ sign here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier than back-substitution is too keep track of the linear relations from the start

$$\begin{align}
24 &= \ \ 1(24)+0(11)\\
11 &=\ \  0(24)+1(11)\\
 2 &=\ \  1(24)-2(11)\ \  =\ \rm  row_1 - 2\cdot row_2\\
 1 &=\! -5(24)\!+\!11(11)\, = \ \rm row_2 - 5\cdot row_3
\end{align}$$

i.e. we perform the Euclidean algorithm on the LHS *and* in parallel on the RHS.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) for much more on this version of the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot, I will use this!

Comment: The answer in the book is $1=6*24+13*(-11)$

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick is to substitute backward from the equations you already have. For example, you have $-11=-6\cdot2+1$, so that means $1=-11+6\cdot2$. Using your first equation, we can re-write $2$ to yield the new equation $1=-11+6\cdot(24+2\cdot-11)$, which implies $\boxed{1=6\cdot24-11\cdot13}$ by distributing the $6$ and combining like terms.